# avgokmts returning incorrect maximum rain from ok mesonet data

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using the `okmesonet` package to get data on rainfall. I've tried using `avgokmts` from this package to calculate the rainfall for each day, but I'm getting non-sensical values.

Get rain data for Norman, OK (cumulative rain in mm over a day at 5 min intervals)

```
library(okmesonet)
rainDat <- okmts(begintime="2016-06-21 00:00:00", endtime="2016-07-04 00:00:00",
          station="NRMN", variables="RAIN", localtime=TRUE)
```

Calculate the max rain per day

```
avgokmts(rainDat, by="day", metric="max")
```

Which returns these values

```
   STID STNM DAY MONTH YEAR  RAIN     Time       Date
1  NRMN  121  21    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-22
2  NRMN  121  22    06 2016  0.25 23:55:00 2016-06-23
3  NRMN  121  23    06 2016 59.70 23:55:00 2016-06-24
4  NRMN  121  24    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-25
5  NRMN  121  25    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-26
6  NRMN  121  26    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-27
7  NRMN  121  27    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-28
8  NRMN  121  28    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-29
9  NRMN  121  29    06 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-06-30
10 NRMN  121  30    06 2016 28.19 23:55:00 2016-07-01
11 NRMN  121  01    07 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-07-02
12 NRMN  121  02    07 2016  0.51 23:55:00 2016-07-03
13 NRMN  121  03    07 2016  0.00 23:55:00 2016-07-04
14 NRMN  121  04    07 2016  0.00 00:00:00 2016-07-04
```

But these rainfall values very clearly don't match up with the rainfall as graphed below (peak rainfall occurs on June 27th and July 3rd).

```
plot(rainDat$TIME, rainDat$RAIN, xlab="Date", ylab="Cumulative Daily Rain (mm)")
```

[image: cumulative rain fall plot]

Why isn't `avgokmts` working in this case? Is there an error in how I'm calling the function? Is there an alternative way to calculate daily rainfall using this dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the pkg author did not deal with the UTC<->CDT conversions properly for the precip readings. Here's a fragile way to get the max precip per day if you are using a single station. The expansion of the procedure to handle multiple stations should just be by adding one more `group_by()` variable.

```
library(okmesonet)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

rainDat <- okmts(begintime="2016-06-21 00:00:00", 
                 endtime="2016-07-04 00:00:00",
                 station="NRMN", 
                 variables="RAIN", 
                 localtime=TRUE)

# Use the pkg calculation -------------------------------------------------

pkg_calc <- avgokmts(rainDat, by="day", metric="max")

# Begin our own calculations ----------------------------------------------

rainDat <- mutate(rainDat, day=format(TIME, "%Y-%m-%d"))

day_precip_max <- function(x) {

  prev_day_last_reading_time <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s 23:55:00", x$day[1]), tz="America/Chicago") -
                                as.difftime(1, unit="days")

  prev_day_last_reading <- rainDat[rainDat$TIME==prev_day_last_reading_time, "RAIN"]

  if (length(prev_day_last_reading) == 0) prev_day_last_reading <- 0

  x <- mutate(x, RAIN=RAIN - prev_day_last_reading)

  data_frame(
    STID=x$STID[1], STNM=x$STNM[1], 
    DAY=substr(x$day[1], 9, 10),
    MONTH=substr(x$day[1], 6, 7),
    YEAR=substr(x$day[1], 1, 4),
    RAIN=max(x$RAIN)
  )

}

new_calc <- group_by(rainDat, day) %>% do(day_precip_max(.)) %>% ungroup()

# Convert to POSIXct for common plotting axis ------------------------------

pkg_calc <- mutate(pkg_calc, day=as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s-%s-%s 23:55:00", YEAR, MONTH, DAY), tz="America/Chicago"))
new_calc <- mutate(new_calc, day=as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s-%s-%s 23:55:00", YEAR, MONTH, DAY), tz="America/Chicago"))

grid.arrange(
  ggplot(rainDat, aes(x=TIME, y=RAIN)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks="1 day", date_labels="%d") +
    labs(x=NULL, y="Rain", title="Raw readings")
,
  ggplot(pkg_calc, aes(x=day, y=RAIN)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks="1 day", date_labels="%d", limits=range(rainDat$TIME)) +
    labs(x=NULL, y="Rain", title="Package aggregation (max)")
,
  ggplot(new_calc, aes(x=day, y=RAIN)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks="1 day", date_labels="%d", limits=range(rainDat$TIME)) +
    labs(x=NULL, y="Rain", title="Manual aggregation (max)")
,
ncol=1
)
```

[image]

I have the plot displaying the max reading at 23:55:00.